# Logical Implication & Injective Functions

Tags: logic

As I understand it, the '$\Rightarrow$' symbol (which stands for the word 'implies') means the following:
Given two statements A and B:

(  ( if (A == true) then (B == true)  )

or

(if (A == false) then ((B == true) or (B == false))) )

or in words: If Statement A is true, B must also be true, though if A is false, B can be either true or false.

The definition of an injective function according to my book and wikipedia is:
$f$ is called injective, if the following holds true: $\;\;f(a) =f(b) \Rightarrow a = b\;\;$
Which means if we apply two elements $a,b \in A$ to $ f: A \rightarrow B$, and the resulting two elements $f(a)$ and $f(b) \in B$ are equal, then the original two values $a,b$ must be the same element, hence $a=b$.

Now comes the part that confuses me: If we apply the definition above to the other, we get the following:

if $f(a)=f(b) \;\;$ then  $\;\; a=b$

or

if $f(a) \neq f(b) \;\;$ then $\; \; a=b \;\;$ or $\; \; a\neq b$

So the last line says if $f(a) \neq f(b)$ then a and b can either be the same element or different elements. The latter is fine, if $ f$ returns two unique elements, the elements $a,b$ applied to the function must also be unique, hence $a \neq b$. But its also possible for $a = b$, which would mean that it is possible to get more than one unique element from $f$, according to the definition.

That last conclusion is of course wrong, since that would be a property of a surjective function and not an injective one. Thanks for your time,

Mark

Comment: I'm having a difficult time identifying what your *real* question or source of confusion is. It seems like you're confusing truth values for the truth table construction of $p\to q$ with negating implications. I think you need to make this question a bit clearer before someone can furnish a quality answer.

Comment: Just to throw this out there in case it was missed:

If a = b, then f(a) = f(b). This is true for *all* functions.

A function is injective if the *converse* holds: if f(a) = f(b), then a = b.

Comment: You are forgetting the key condition that makes the  implication false, namely (in your non-standard notation) if (( A == true) and (B == false)).  Otherwise, the implication is true.

Comment: You are forgetting that functions are generally defined by definition to have $x_1=x_2 \rightarrow F(x_1)=F(x_2)$, and that numbers  in the domain, are totally ordered  $<, =, >$by definition (insofar as they are numbers). Do not confuse it with a the way almost agreeing measure are defined in qualitative probability - as we already are dealing with two extra concepts, that of number, the domain element are ordered by definition, and that of a function. So its essentially the same as an order embedding or strong representation where all bi-conditionals hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a relation $R=\{(x,y)|x\in A, y\in B\}$ between two sets, $A$ and $B$, is such that $(x,y) \in R$ *and* $(x,z) \in R$ for $x \in A$, $y,z \in B$, then $R$ is **not** a functional relation, that is, $R$ is not a map (let alone being surjective).

Now,

$$(f(x)\neq f(y)) \implies (x \neq y \vee x=y)$$

It is what formal logic implies. But in this particular case, we are working within other (more "specific") theories (set theory) and thus we have to bare in mind definitions and propositions of such theories.

In particular,

$$(f(x)\neq f(y)) \implies (x \neq y).$$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but would formal logic allow combining the two statements in your posted answer into one? as in $ f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow (x = y) \newline (f(x) \neq f(y) \Rightarrow (x \neq y \or x = y) \newline f(x) \neq f(y) \Rightarrow (x \neq y)$ would combine to $f(x) = f(y) \Leftrightarrow x = y$.

Answer (score 2):

"But its also possible for a=b"
That doesn't mean you must have at least some (a,b) such that a=b.
When you have something like 
*For All x, P(x) or Q(x)*, all you can tell is that, for any particular x instance, either P(x) holds, Q(x) holds or both hold true. You cannot assume that P(y) will hold for some y and Q(z) will hold for some z.

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong to say this would mean $f$ was surjective. If $f(a)$ can be two different values (ie $f(a) \neq f(b)$ but $a=b$) then the function is not *well defined* as it does not know where to map $a$ to.

Hence that part of the implication is redundant as it contradicts the definition of $f$ being a function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The statement $f(x)\neq f(y)\implies x=y \vee x\neq y$ does not mean that $f(x)$ may have more than one result for any $x$.   It just means that *at least one* of the disjunction's clauses will be true.   Since they are complementary, that is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

The erroneous conclusion, that "it is possible to get more than one unique element from $f$," seems to arise from this sentence:

> if $f(a) \neq f(b) $ then $a=b$ or $a\neq b$

Given that $f(a)=f(b) \implies a = b$, the sentence above is true, but only if the "or" is interpreted appropriately.
A correct interpretation of the highlighted sentence
is that for every possible choice of $a$ and $b$
with which we can instantiate that sentence, at least one of the two
clauses connected by the "or" is true.
The sentence is true because every
possible choice of $a$ and $b$ that makes $f(a) \neq f(b)$ true
also makes $a\neq b$ true; 
this is a consequence of the fact that $f$ is a function.
And whenever $a\neq b$ is true, "$a=b$ or $a\neq b$" is true as well.

(Actually, the "given" in the previous paragraph is not really necessary;
the highlighted sentence is true regardless any other facts,
because "$a=b$ or $a\neq b$" is a tautology. But I do not think that has any
bearing on how the erroneous conclusion arose.)

In order to conclude that "it's also possible for $a=b$,"
I think you have to be interpreting
"if $f(a) \neq f(b)$ then $a=b$ or $a\neq b$"
incorrectly.
You seem to be assuming that given any sentence of the form
"if $P(a,b)$ then $Q(a,b)$ or $R(a,b)$" 
(where $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are Boolean-valued formulas),
you can draw three conclusions:

1. There are choices of $a$ and $b$ that make $P(a,b)$ true.
2. There are choices of $a$ and $b$ that make $P(a,b)$ true and also make $Q(a,b)$ true.
3. There are choices of $a$ and $b$ that make $P(a,b)$ true and also make $R(a,b)$ true.

In fact *none* of these three conclusions is valid.
Given an arbitrary statement of the form
"if $P(a,b)$ then $Q(a,b)$ or $R(a,b)$" which is known to be true,
it might be the case that $P(a,b)$ is never true,
or it might be that every time $P(a,b)$ is true, $R(a,b)$ is true
and $Q(a,b)$ is false.

In the particular case of "if $f(a) \neq f(b)$ then $a=b$ or $a\neq b$,"
where we are given that $f$ is an injective function,
**if** it is also true that the domain of $f$ has more than one element
then there are choices of $a$ and $b$ that make $f(a) \neq f(b)$ true.
(And that bold-faced "if" is a very important "if"!)
But in every such case, the reason that "$a=b$ or $a\neq b$" is true
is because $a\neq b$ is true; *in every single case* where
$f(a) \neq f(b)$ is true, $a=b$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

The usual definition of logical implication:

> $A\implies B \equiv \neg [A\land \neg B] $.

From this definition, we can derive the contra-positive rule:

> From $A\implies B$, we can infer that $\neg B \implies \neg A$

So, from $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$, we can infer that $a\ne b \implies f(a)\ne f(b)$.